# AdMob MobileAds.initialize() pro and contra

Tags: android, admob

I'm currently not using `MobileAds.initialize()` and everything works fine.

Some developers report that this call can take nearly [200 ms](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/kayQ3VZJqkU/v8yeiD-SAQAJ) to complete and might cause [ANR](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/kayQ3VZJqkU/ZKy4GgrxAwAJ).

Does this code

```
MobileAds.initialize();
interstitialAd.loadAd();
```

take the same time to execute on fresh app start as just

```
interstitialAd.loadAd(); //?
```

On the other hand, [App ID](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6232340) is required to use certain features in AdMob.

What are these features?